Using @starting-style and allow-discrete, how to remove a dialog element after it is closed？
Using @starting-style and allow-discrete, how to remove a dialog element after it is closed and transitioned？
Using @starting-style and allow-discrete to do the transition entry and exit of dialog.I need to remove the dialog element after closing dialog. I didn't want a redundant element to exist in the DOM. Here is the code i use.
dialog {
  &,
  &::backdrop {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.15s, display 0.15s allow-discrete, overlay 0.15s allow-discrete;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  &::backdrop {
    background-color: black;
  }
  &:modal {
    opacity: 1;
    &::backdrop {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
    @starting-style {
      &,
      &::backdrop {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}

<button type="button">open dialog</button>

document.querySelector('button').onclick = event => {
  const dialog = document.createElement('dialog')
  const close_button = event.currentTarget.cloneNode()
  close_button.textContent = 'close'
  close_button.onclick = () => dialog.close()
  dialog.append(close_button)
  
  // 1.
  // This will cause the click to close immediately after triggering remove, losing the exit transition
  // dialog.onclose = Element.prototype.remove

  // 2.
  // According to the specifications, in the case where a transition is removed before completion, such as if the transition-property is removed or display is set to none, then the event will not be generated.
  // dialog.onclose = () => {
  //   dialog.ontransitionend = Element.prototype.remove
  // }
  
  // 3.
  // After entering the transition, register a transitionstart event, listen to exit the transition, time to 150ms, and then remove dialog.
  // dialog.addEventListener(
  //   'transitionend',
  //   () => {
  //     dialog.ontransitionstart = () => setTimeout(() => dialog.remove(), 150)
  //   },
  //   {once: true}
  // )
  document.body.append(dialog)
  dialog.showModal()
}

I used three methods, none of which solved my problem well, either by not implementing it or by being too ugly.

I don't know why, but in some cases Chrome v131 emits the transitioncancel instead of transitionend event.
Here is my workaround:
const ac = new AbortController()

const handleTransitionEnd = (transitionEvent) => {
  if (
    // Closed
    !dialogElement.open &&
    // Not a backdrop
    !transitionEvent.pseudoElement &&
    // Use single property to run once
    transitionEvent.propertyName === 'display'
  ) {
    // Your callback here
    transitionEvent.target.remove()

    ac.abort()
  }
}

// Note: Just one following events is emitted
dialogElement.addEventListener('transitionend', handleTransitionEnd, { signal: ac.signal })
dialogElement.addEventListener('transitioncancel', handleTransitionEnd, { signal: ac.signal })

Notes:

Chrome v131 doesn't emit any transition event for ESC key.
Firefox v133 doesn't emit any transition event

